# Magento 1.9 Customer Login Stopped Working

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, nginx, apache

Server: Dedicated, Apache 2.4, Nginx, Redis, CPanel/WHM, Site using FPC extension Mirasvit

1. We have an Magento 1.9 site with the above setup - since last week all of sudden customers are no longer to login to there accounts.

When entering the user and pass the user is returned back to the login page and no error is showing,

I have tried the suggested fixes 
[Magento 1.9 customer login not working](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/175955/magento-1-9-customer-login-not-working)

Previously there was no cookie domain however I still tried.

and form_key

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19712499/magento-customer-login-page-redirects-to-itself-without-any-error

Also checked all directory and file permission.

2. I have also noticed that I am no longer able to run reindex via SSH
3. The cron is no longer working - it is setup correct and was working previously.

Everything was working until last week and this just happen suddenly - I am out of ideas as I think this may also be some server setting change which is not allowing server software or php to be executed on the site.

Please can anyone suggest any more fixes asap - as I am having a nightmare.
Thank You

Comment: cron issue is now fixed but the others still remain please provide suggestions

Comment: Can no one offer any help with this any suggestions